# Get GA client id from events

Tags: google-analytics

Hi Im using Query Explorer to get the events from my users. What I know is that the Google Analytics SDK will create a unique GA client ID for each of my users. But how do I know the client ID of a certain event? I cannot find this in the default dimension. I know that I can use custom dimension and set this client ID there. But isn't it that GA by default should be tracking this client ID and attaching to each event?

Answer (score 2):

This might not be in scope for the OverFlow site and might better suited for the webmaster forum.

By default, GA creates unique identifiers per user by storing a cookie `_ga` in the browser. This will be sent with every hit to GA to associate that hit to the user/session.

Each event you fire will be a hit with the cookie id and a session identifier.

However, Client ID is not a default dimension you can query against in the GA UI. If you have the Premium version, you get the value as a column in BigQuery. However, if you want it in GA, most people go the route of creating a new custom dimension X and using customTasks in their tagging implementations to store the value in the custom dimension. Then it should address your concern